# Returning only the contents before and after a line number with different matching words

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, cygwin

I am using cygwin.

I have known line# in my hand. Script should look for the first occurrence of the string `mono` above a specified line number and look for the first occurrence of the string `/mono` below the specified line numbers and return only the contents between those `mono` and `/mono`.

**Input:**

```
I have known line # in my hand.  
Script should look for the first occurrence of word mono  
not monoono  
above a specified line #  
and look for the  
first occurrence of word /mono below the specified line #s  
and return ONLY the contents between those 'mono' and /mono
```

**Expected Output**

```
mono 
not monoono  
above a specified line #  
and look for the  
first occurrence of word /mono
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to show an example of input and expected output

Comment: Philippos . . Thanks. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compact version with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 'H;4!d;g;s/.*\<mono\>/mono/;:a;N;s_/mono\>.*_/mono_;Ta' in
```

Explanation:

- `H` collects all lines in the hold space
- `4!d` suppresses all output except for 4th line
- At 4th line, move the hold space to the pattern space (`g`) and remove everything upto the word `mono` with the `s` command
- `:a; ... ;Ta` forms a loop appending lines with `N` until `/mono` is read

Comment: Philippos ... Awesome. Works perfectly.  One stuff I messed here. The search terms are <mono> and </mono>. If you can help, that's great.

Comment: @SamuelFinny In this case you don't even need extended regular expressions. You can use a portable script like `sed -e 'H;4!d;g;s/.*<mono>/<mono>/;:a' -e 'N;s_</mono>.*_</mono>_;Ta'`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v L=4 '(NR<L && $0 ~ /\<mono\>/){Pnr=NR;gsub(/^.*\<mono\>/,"mono"); P=$0;next}
     (!Nnr && $0 ~ /\/\<mono\>/){Nnr=NR;gsub(/\/\<mono\>.*/,"/mono"); N=$0}
     (NR!=FNR && P){print P;P=""}(FNR>Pnr && FNR <Nnr ){print} END{print N}' in in
```

Will result what is between `mono` ~ `/mono`: first occurrences around specific line#4 here.

```
mono
not monoono
above a specified line #
and look for the
first occurrence of word /mono
```

If you didn't want matched lines after matched *pattern*, it would be shortest:

```
awk -v L=4 '(NR<L && $0 ~ /\<mono\>/){Pnr=NR;next}
    (!Nnr && $0 ~ /\/\<mono\>/){Nnr=NR}
    (FNR>Pnr && FNR <Nnr)' in in
```

Comment: Thanks. I have taken your input and edited the original post. Can we get the output like  mono
not monoono
above a specified line #
and look for the
first occurrence of word /mono

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I have copied the below contents from my cygwin console. Can you pls let me know where I am going wrong.   awk -v L=4 '(!Pnr && NR<L && $0 ~ /\<mono\>/)  
>             { Pnr=NR;gsub(/^.*\<mono\>/,"mono"); print; next}  
>             (!Nnr && NR>L && $0 ~ /\/\<mono\>/)  
>             { Nnr=NR;gsub(/\/\<mono\>.*/,"/mono"); print; next}  
>             ( Pnr && !Nnr){print;}  
> ' test.txt  
I have known line # in my hand.  
mono  
not monoono  
above a specified line #  
and look for the  
mono below the specified line #s  
mono

Comment: please see updated answer